# Way to see invisible entities in var (ex. \n)

Tags: javascript

I just had a var I believed to be equal to `""` or `undefined`. It turned out it was equal to `\r`. I couldn't see this until I wrapped the var in quotes and outputted it to the console and I saw the line break. Is their any way I could have saw `\r` rather than nothing? Perhaps wrapping it in some function which will output `\r` or `\n` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general you could use something like JSON:

```
var str = "\r";
alert( JSON.stringify(str) );
// will alert "\u000d" instead of 'nothing'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex check?

```
/\r/.test( "\r\n" )
```

Or a regex replacement for all carriage returns with a string:

```
"\r\n".replace( /\r/g, 'i just replaced a carriage return' )
```

You can also probably do an enumeration on the string and check the charCode to see if it equates to the carriage return one, then spit out the index in which it lives relative to the string.

EDIT: If you want to check if a string contains anything, then use `.length` as others have stated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use the string’s `length` method to see whether it’s empty:

   ```
   "\r".length; // → 1
   ```
2. You could encode the string as JSON — which is built into newer browsers (and available as [a library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older ones):

   ```
   JSON.stringify("\r"); // → ""\r""
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "\r";
if (str) {
    // The var is not empty, null, or undefined...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any built-in function.

If I suspect something like this, I generally put some recognizable characters around it -- like you did with quotes -- and also print the length, so if the length is greater than the number of characters I can see, I know there must be something invisible.

Occassionally when it's really puzzling I've written a little function to loop through the characters in a string and dump their numeric values. ASCII values less than 32 are often invisible.